# No csm configuration found

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am using the following steps in ec2 instance ubuntu to push the logs from the server to AWS cloud watch
cloud watch setup

1. sudo wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
2. sudo dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
3. sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard
4. sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json

But when I am running the last command I am getting the following error `No csm configuration found.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV8cP.png)

Why its giving this error not sending logs to the aws cloudwatch